# Use of 's' in consecutive words

Tags: grammar, phrases

I am trying to figure out which of the following sentences is the correct one.

"A place where family becomes friends" or "A place where family becomes friend"

Answer (score 1):

Since **family** is a collective noun, the verb **belonging** can be in either singular or plural form.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/matching-verbs-to-collective-nouns) states that:

> In American English, most collective nouns are treated as singular, with a singular verb:
>   *"A place where family **becomes** friends”.*
>
> In British English, most collective nouns can be treated as singular or plural:
>   *"A place where family **become** friends"*

Since "family" is plural, "friend" must also be in plural form. Therefore, both of the above sentences are correct.

Comment: But _family_ is **not** plural; it’s singular. Its plural is _families_. It’s a collective noun, which means it is semantically (at least optionally) equivalent to a plural, but it is not itself plural. _Friend_ doesn’t necessarily have to be plural either, but as with most count nouns, it cannot appear in the singular without a determiner. “A place where your family becomes your friend” is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: _Family_ is plural enough to trigger optional plural agreement in tags: _Your family is still in Bulgaria, aren't they?_ The presenting problem is what to do with an equational sentence where the two NPs are different in number, and  as phrased, it's unclear what it means. Does your family suddenly stop fighting? Do several members become more friendly? To whom? How many people are involved, anyway?